# How to ask for a Code Review of one individual file in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I want to use the TFS 2013 Code Review system to ask a colleague to have a look at the current or latest version of *one specific file*. I cannot seem to find an option to do so. Is this possible?

I've tried:

- Right-clicking the file in Solution Explorer, checking the Source Control context menu, but the option to ask for a review is not there;
- [This solution from a blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slange/archive/2012/07/13/vs-tfs-2012-tidbits-requesting-a-code-review-on-code-already-checked-in.aspx) where you request the review from a file's "View History" overview, but this ended up sending a review for the entire changeset instead of that one file;
- Opening the file and right-clicking the tab header, but no Source Control options are available in that context menu;
- Check out the options in the Team Explorer, but I couldn't find an option to do what I want;

**Is it even *possible* to request a Code Review of one specific file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the file out and in Pending Changes exclude everything else, leaving just the one file. Then from Pending Changes window => Actions => Request Review but this obviously won't highlight your changes as I'm assuming they have already been committed.

Comment: Will check out your suggestion / workaround in a bit. (PS. There *are no* changes, I want someone to have a look at a file created by others, quite some time ago.)

Comment: Oh, in that case, the above will definitely work then ;)

Comment: Tested and confirms. A bit fiddly, but I guess if it works it works :-)